# App freezes when synchronization with dropbox/Evernote utility turned on

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api, evernote, ios12

I am facing an issue . Few weeks back I updated my iPhone to iOS 12.1 . I have an iOS app where it can synchronize with dropbox or Evernote. 
After updating to iOS 12.1, app freezes when it try to synchronize with dropbox/Evernote. Below is error snippet :

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent_id:
    0x211b1c95c <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x177
    0x211b1c960 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x211b1c964 <+8>:  b.lo   0x211b1c97c               ; <+32>
    0x211b1c968 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x211b1c96c <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x211b1c970 <+20>: bl     0x211b10800               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x211b1c974 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x211b1c978 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x211b1c97c <+32>: ret
```

I have looked up all over the internet but didn't found the solution. Below are the links :
    [https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/681]

[https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62335]

[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17936]

Any kind of help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

P.S. App works fine on <12.

Comment: What's the synchronizing API? It seems that you are blocking the main thread.

Comment: @Larme I am using ObjectiveDropboxOfficial.framework for synchronizing .